# Grouping COUNT by date and id from foreign table

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to get the count of reports made by id_type and by day in the same result set.

My current query displays the total reports for each type, but doesn't separate the reports by day as well.

```
SELECT DATE(report.date_insert) AS date_insert, type.name, count(report.id_type) as number_of_orders
from type
left join report
on (type.id_type = report.id_type)
group by type.id_type
```

As you can see, the only difference between them, is that i've changed the value for `type.id_type = XX`, but this is not the effective way to achieve my requirement.

Another important requirement is that, if there are no reports from an `id_type` in a day where at least another `id_type` does have reports, there should be a result with the count of zero.

I've created a fiddle with the structure and some sample data, where id_type=1 should have 0 reports, id_type=2 should have 8 reports, and id_type=3 should have 5 reports.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ceb48/2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join with a subquery that gets all the different dates, and then add the date to the grouping.

```
SELECT alldates.date_insert, type.name, IFNULL(COUNT(report.id_type), 0) AS number_of_orders
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date_insert) AS date_insert
    FROM report) AS alldates
CROSS JOIN type
LEFT JOIN report ON type.id_type = report.id_type AND alldates.date_insert = DATE(report.date_insert)
GROUP BY alldates.date_insert, type.id_type
ORDER BY alldates.date_insert, type.name
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ceb48/5)